# How to auto verify one time password in android application

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, mobile

I am working on a project where I want to implement functionality where system automatically reads one time password from phone and verify it. I am not able to find any help on this. Quick help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement broadcast receiver for message

```
public class SmsListener extends BroadcastReceiver{

private SharedPreferences preferences;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if(intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")){
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();           //---get the SMS message passed in---
        SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
        String msg_from;
        if (bundle != null){
            //---retrieve the SMS message received---
            try{
                Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                for(int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
                    msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
                    msg_from = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                    String msgBody = msgs[i].getMessageBody();
                }
            }catch(Exception e){
                       Log.d("Exception caught",e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

//In manifiest file

```
<receiver android:name=".listener.SmsListener">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
</intent-filter>
```

//permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
```

//when your server send the message then it would be detected in receiver

Comment: sure..I working to implement it. Will update mark this complete once I m done with implementation :)